# How to create a drop down list in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to create a drop down list in an ASP.NET MVC3 view based on a list of allowed values linked to the model.

So far, in my model, I've got:

```
namespace NS 
{
    public class Model
    {
        public Model() 
        {
            Status = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "New", Value = "New" });
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PaymentPending", Value = "PaymentPending" });
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PaymentProcessed", Value = "PaymentProcessed" });
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dispatched", Value = "Dispatched" });
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Complete", Value = "Complete" });
            Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cancelled", Value = "Cancelled" });
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
    } // class Model
} // NS
```

(obviously trimming unneccessary stuff out)

Then in my view I've got:

```
@model NS.Model
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.Status)
```

As looking at answers on SO seems to suggest. But I get an error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments

Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error message is pretty self-explanatory, the [**DropDownListFor helper**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462.aspx) takes two arguments.

modify your model to have a property to contain the selected value

```
public class Model
{
public Model() {
  Status = new List<SelectListItem>();
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "New", Value = "New" });
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PaymentPending", Value = "PaymentPending" });
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "PaymentProcessed", Value = "PaymentProcessed" });
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dispatched", Value = "Dispatched" });
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Complete", Value = "Complete" });
  Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cancelled", Value = "Cancelled" });
}
public List<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
public string SelectedVal{get;set;}
}
```

then in the view

```
@NS.Model
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.SelectedVal, x.Status)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the selected value of the dropdown list from the model. The second value is the list of statuses.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.SelectedValue, Model.Status)
```